# Check variable if it is in a list

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python, and I was wondering if there was a succinct way of testing a value to see if it is one of the values in the list, similar to a SQL WHERE clause.  Sorry if this is a basic question.

```
MsUpdate.UpdateClassificationTitle in (
        'Critical Updates',
        'Feature Packs',
        'Security Updates',
        'Tools',
        'Update Rollups',
        'Updates',
        )
```

i.e, I want to write:

```
if MsUpdate.UpdateClassificationTitle in (
        'Critical Updates',
        'Feature Packs',
        'Security Updates',
        'Tools',
        'Update Rollups',
        'Updates'
        ):  
    then_do_something()
```

Comment: Yes, do that, except use the correct syntax for lists.

Comment: Is that a Python tuple or an SQL set? Because it's not a Python list.

Comment: Change '(' and ')' to '[' and ']', respectively. :)

Answer (score 16):

Seems succinct enough, but if you're using it more than once you should name the tuple:

```
titles = ('Critical Updates',
    'Feature Packs',
    'Security Updates',
    'Tools',
    'Update Rollups',
    'Updates')

if MsUpdate.UpdateClassificationTitle in titles:  
    do_something_with_update(MsUpdate)
```

Tuples use parenthesis.  If you want a list change it to square brackets.  Or use a set, which has faster lookups.

Answer (score 15):

It's quite straightforward:

```
sample = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

if 'four' in sample:
   print True
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are using in not is for example

```
username = ["Bob", "Kyle"]

name = "Kyle"

if name in username:
    print("step 1")
    login = 1
else:
    print("Invalid User")
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please be sure your Python code is formatted properly.  The current formatting will not compile.  You can use the `edit` button to modify your answer.